# Avoid the http handler to kill the page life cycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, page-lifecycle

I’m building an asp.net web application; I’m using an http handler as a filter, because I want the user to be redirected to a certain page if a condition is true. Problem is if the condition is false the page doesn’t load because the http handlers kill the life cycle of the page itself…so, is there any way to avoid this and to load the page properly or am I supposed to use another object to filter?

Answer (score 1):

A handler, as its name suggests, must completely **handle** the request. If you want every request to be examined and filtered, you want to use an `HttpModule`.

A good 'getting started' guide can be found [here](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/08/15/Developing-IIS7-web-server-features-with-the-.NET-framework.aspx).